# which configuration applies vscode to git bash and how to copy it?

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I am trying to figure out what does do vscode when it opens their integrated terminal using git bash.

There a couple of differences in how the terminal works standalone vs  git bash inside vscode. For example the colors when I run a jest test

Standalone:

[image: standalone git bash]

Inside vscode:

[image: inside vscode]

Another difference is what happens when I do an `npm install`. In standalone mode I get no feedback whatsoever about what is happening until the process is done. Inside vscode I get this:

[image]

This is specially frustrating when I need to install the dependencies of a big new cloned project because sometimes I do not know if git bash crashed or it is still running.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is likely due to the setting of the `TERM` environment variable, which specifies the terminal type in use. Git Bash uses one setting for this value (often `cygwin`), and Visual Studio Code usually uses `xterm-256color`.

This terminal type specifies capabilities, and the `cygwin` terminal type supports fewer colors (8) than `xterm-256color` (which supports 256). In addition, programs written in JavaScript often don't use the system terminal information database, instead relying on a hard-coded list of terminal types, so even if `cygwin` supports some features, if the JavaScript libraries don't know that it does, program such as `npm` will lack support for using those features and fall back to a simpler mode.

Comment: I see. I do have in [my config](//i.imgur.com/8HmAwf0.png) `xterm-256` color as Type and I do see some colors (for example the text 'jest-reporter' have the same color in both of my screenshots). So is there no way to force this behavior like vscode does?

Comment: You'd want to check that the terminal type is actually being set to that value. Running `echo $TERM` in Git bash should print `xterm-256color` if that's the type that's set. If not, you can try setting `export TERM=xterm-256color`, but if the terminal doesn't support that setting, then it will likely not render correctly.

Comment: It says 256. Also I am not sure if I should mark you answer as correct since technically I does says it can NOT be copied.